# Expand and collapse cells in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview. Some cells contain images, other text.

I want to be able to collapse and expand the cells. In order to be able to do so I did the following:

I created a variable `isExpanded = true`
In cellForRowAt I check if the cell contains text and then...

```swift
 if textIsExpanded {
               
  cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
  cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
 }
```

so that the cell can be as tall as the text inside of it.

In the action I toggle `textIsExpanded` and reload the table:

```swift
 textIsExpanded.toggle()
 table.reloadData()
```

This procedure perfectly works with tableviews only containing text.

Something that would work was expanding the if statement and in the false branch calling:

```swift
 cell.textLabel?.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
 cell.textLabel?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

BUT this doesn't work when I toggle the variable, this only works on launch.

How can I collapse and expand back the cells in my tableview?

Comment: The expandable/collapsible tableView is supposed to tableView's header.  So how does tableView's cellForRowAt delegate method come into play?

Comment: I don't neeed an expandable tableview, i need an expandable cell This is why i use the cellForRowAt.

Answer (score 0):

Create your cell with a stack of two views, Upper view and lower View, Add a Bool key to your Model isExpandable that is triggered and changed on didSelect and check on this to hide or show your view, EIther keep the text as text or TextView up to you.

[image: Cell Design]

[image: Set Your cell with the data]

[image: Trigger this on didselect]